# ANGULAR2-RC3 Routing : Can't resolve all parameters for provideRouter: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, routes

I have update my project to the last rc3 version of angular.

This is my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.1.10",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.28",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "del": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.4",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

I change my route like this in main.ts :

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path:'dashboard', component: ExchangeDasboardComponent},
    {path:'', component: CreateAccountComponent},
    {path:'exchange', component: ExchangeComponent}
];


bootstrap(IsdhComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS,     provideRouter(routes)]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When I launch the application, i have this error :

```
browser_adapter.ts:74Error: Can't resolve all parameters for provideRouter:  (?, ?).
    at new BaseException     (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:20:23)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata     (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:292:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:173:26)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:327:30)
    at Array.map (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:315:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:124:34)
    at RuntimeCompiler.resolveComponent (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:38:47)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:147:37)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:344:26)
```

What did i do wrong? I have follow this documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Have you imported provideRouter like this? import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from
'@angular/router';

Comment: Yes, i have this import :import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

Comment: Can you reproduce in http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview ?

Answer (score 2):

My bad,

During the migration, I have put this in my root component :

```
    providers : [provideRouter]
```

I have remove it, and it's work correctly.